Detect presence of series with same and close numbers with awk
I have thousands of text files with integer numbers. Now, I want to know which text files contain long series with dozens of same or close numbers. I consider numbers to be close, if the difference of them is around 5.
In general, I would like to rate the text files with percentage values between 0% and 100%. 0% would mean that all numbers are equal, low percentages would mean there are long series with same and close numbers, and 100% would mean that all numbers are totally random.
I don't have any strict requirements as to which exact percentages come out as long as the solution script is able to evaluate number sequences that contain long series of equal or similar numbers with low percentages and number sequences without such series with high percentages. I want to work with probabilities instead of strict limits.
In my actual text files, every number is in a single line. However, I use spaces instead of newlines as delimiter in my examples for readability.
Minimized examples:
4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4 4
-> exact 0% as the entire line is one long series of the same number

2 9 21 17 12 2 2 5 4 6 5 6 6 6 7 6 7 5 3 6 6 5 7 7 6 6 5 6 7 6 7 5 7 6 6 6 5 6 6 5 6 78
-> much less than 50% as there is a long series with numbers between 5 and 7

20 15 1 2 1 3 2 1 3 18 20 6 12 35 32 35 34 34 34 34 33 34 33 36 44 68 33 32 34 33 53 87
-> less than 50% as there is a series of numbers (32..35), but interrupted by 44+68

12 28 38 44 22 38 16 14 23 45 17 39 29 2 5 15 11 7 2 8 2 14 10 1 14 3 2 2 9 10 4 22 7 1
-> up to 100% as there are no series of same or close numbers

Currently, I use the standard deviation in percent:
{
   a += $1;
   b[++i] = $1
} END {
   m = a / NR;
   for (i in b) {
      d += (b[i] - m) ^ 2
   }
   print int(sqrt(d / NR) * 100 / m + 0.5)
}

After executing this script, I manually check all text files with a result of less than 100%. This works somehow, but is anything but perfect. Is there any better approach to detect text files contain long series with the same or close numbers?
For context, each text file represents a user session, and each number represents the number of requests in that minute. For example, 4 7 6 would mean that the user was active for three minutes and made 4 requests in the first minute, 7 requests in the second minute, and 6 requests in the third minute. Long series of the same or close numbers are often a sign of bots rather than humans.

Also [edit] your question to define values for "long" and "close" in the statement "long series with the same or close numbers?" with respect to the sample input you provide.

Please replace the expected output ranges with actual percentage value for each input line and explain how the percentages should be calculated as there are various possibilities. You say "Currently, I use the standard deviation in percent:" but then you also say that's "anything but perfect." so clearly that's NOT what you want but it's not clear how you do want percentages calculated.

@EdMorton: I don't have any strict requirements as to which exact percentages come out. I am looking for an awk script to evaluate number sequences that contain long series of equal or similar numbers with low percentages and number sequences without such series with high percentages.

@markp-fuso In my real text files, all numbers are separates by newlines. I used spaces instead of newlines in my question for readability.

It would appear you are trying to test randomness?

@dawg Testing for randomness sounds like a great idea. However, I don't know any command line tool nor how to implement any of these algorithms in an efficient way.

@dawg Without knowing the underlying distribution/length of the data there can't be a concise easy test for randomness, e.g. 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 can be perfectly random, or not.

I think that the number of records would be the length of the data, no?

I'd just not call it test for randomness, rather finding the distribution or patterns within some data.

Your question is a bit too vague for stackoverflow and it is not really a programming question, it is more a question about data analysis techniques. Before it becomes a programming question you should probably clearly define "long series", "same and close numbers", etc. Try maybe here. And if you need some statistical metrics about your data you should probably look at something like datamash, instead of awk.

I don't know how you want percentages to be calculated but the following, using any awk, will tell you for each value in each input line how many "close" (i.e. plus or minus a delta you provide) values occur within a "long" (i.e. some length of neighboring values you provide) series of values exist:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
        delta = (delta == "" ? 0 : delta)
    }
    {
        thisLong = (long == "" ? NF : long)
        numInRange = 0
        rangeBeg = rangeEnd = $1
        delete maxRange
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            valBeg = $i - delta
            valEnd = $i + delta
            posBeg = (i - thisLong >  1 ? i - thisLong : 1)
            posEnd = (i + thisLong < NF ? i + thisLong : NF)
            range = 0
            for ( j=posBeg; j<=posEnd; j++ ) {
                if ( (valBeg <= $j) && ($j <= valEnd) ) {
                    range++
                    maxRange[i] = (range >= maxRange[i] ? range : maxRange[i])
                }
                ###
                # Add:
                #    else { range = 0 }
                # here if you want to reset the count if values
                # outside of the valBeg - valEnd range occur
                # between posBeg and posEnd.
            }
        }
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            printf "%d:%d%s", $i, maxRange[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
        }
    }


$ awk -f tst.awk file
4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44 4:44
2:3 9:1 21:1 17:1 12:1 2:3 2:3 5:9 4:1 6:17 5:9 6:17 6:17 6:17 7:7 6:17 7:7 5:9 3:1 6:17 6:17 5:9 7:7 7:7 6:17 6:17 5:9 6:17 7:7 6:17 7:7 5:9 7:7 6:17 6:17 6:17 5:9 6:17 6:17 5:9 6:17 5:9
20:2 15:1 1:3 2:2 1:3 3:2 2:2 1:3 3:2 18:1 20:2 6:1 12:1 35:2 32:3 35:2 34:7 34:7 34:7 34:7 33:4 34:7 33:4 36:1 44:1 68:1 33:4 32:3 34:7 33:4 34:7 32:3
12:1 28:1 38:2 44:1 22:2 38:2 16:1 14:3 23:1 45:1 17:1 39:1 29:1 2:5 5:1 15:1 11:1 7:2 2:5 8:1 2:5 14:3 10:2 1:1 14:3 3:1 2:5 2:5 9:1 10:2 4:1 22:2 7:2


$ awk -v delta=2 -v long=10 -f tst.awk file
4:11 4:12 4:13 4:14 4:15 4:16 4:17 4:18 4:19 4:20 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:21 4:20 4:19 4:18 4:17 4:16 4:15 4:14 4:13 4:12 4:11
2:4 9:1 21:1 17:1 12:1 2:4 2:4 5:11 4:13 6:12 5:14 6:14 6:15 6:16 7:16 6:18 7:18 5:21 3:6 6:20 6:20 5:21 7:20 7:20 6:20 6:20 5:21 6:20 7:20 6:21 7:21 5:21 7:20 6:19 6:18 6:17 5:16 6:15 6:14 5:13 6:12 5:11
20:3 15:1 1:7 2:7 1:7 3:7 2:7 1:7 3:7 18:3 20:3 6:1 12:1 35:10 32:8 35:10 34:12 34:13 34:14 34:15 33:15 34:17 33:16 36:10 44:1 68:1 33:13 32:12 34:12 33:10 34:10 32:8
12:2 28:1 38:3 44:2 22:2 38:3 16:4 14:4 23:2 45:2 17:3 39:3 29:1 2:4 5:2 15:6 11:2 7:3 2:7 8:5 2:8 14:3 10:5 1:7 14:3 3:7 2:7 2:7 9:5 10:4 4:5 22:1 7:2

Hopefully you can take those values and determine whatever "percentage" you want to calculate, e.g. maybe you want to take the highest of the maxRanges[i] values and divide by the "long" value, or maybe you want to count how many of the maxRanges[i] values are above some threshold or maybe you want to count how many maxRanges[i] are 1 (meaning unique numbers) then divide that by long, e.g.:
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
        delta = (delta == "" ? 0 : delta)
    }
    {
        thisLong = (long == "" ? NF : long)
        numInRange = 0
        rangeBeg = rangeEnd = $1
        delete maxRange
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            valBeg = $i - delta
            valEnd = $i + delta
            posBeg = (i - thisLong >  1 ? i - thisLong : 1)
            posEnd = (i + thisLong < NF ? i + thisLong : NF)
            range = 0
            for ( j=posBeg; j<=posEnd; j++ ) {
                if ( (valBeg <= $j) && ($j <= valEnd) ) {
                    range++
                    maxRange[i] = (range >= maxRange[i] ? range : maxRange[i])
                }
            }
        }
        numUnique = 0
        for ( i=1; i<=NF; i++ ) {
            # printf "%d:%d%s", $i, maxRange[i], (i<NF ? OFS : ORS)
            if ( maxRange[i] == 1 ) {
                numUnique++
            }
        }
        printf "%d%%\n", ((thisLong - numUnique) * 100) / thisLong
    }


$ awk -f tst.awk file
100%
85%
78%
48%

or something else. You just have to decide what you want X and Y to be in the calculation X * 100 / Y.

Thanks for the solution! I'll have to play around with it for a while :)

Finding the ratio between sum of consecutive numbers and the total number of entries. Doesn't take close numbers into consideration.
Also inverting the ratios as requested in the question.
% awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
          if(prev==$i){a[$i]++}
          prev=$i
        }
        for(i in a){
          x+=a[i] + 1
        } 
        print 100-(x/NF*100); x=0; delete a}' file
72.5
74.1573
81.1667
87.1622
87.7828
90.583
88.5246

With boolean output e.g. < 85 (gawk and mawk only)
% awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
          if(prev==$i){a[$i]++}
          prev=$i
        }
        for(i in a){
          x+=a[i] + 1
        } 
        print 100-(x/NF*100) < 85; x=0; delete a}' file
1
1
1
0
0
0
0

Note, output shown uses the originally posted data
On new data:
% awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if(prev==$i){a[$i]++}; prev=$i}; for(i in a){x+=a[i] + 1}; print 100-(x/NF*100); x=0; delete a}' file_new
0
71.4286
87.5
94.1176

Data
% cat file
2 12 18 13 5 4 5 4 7 5 6 7 6 6 6 6 4 5 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 5 7 6 7 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 5 5 6 6 4 5 5 13 30 18 14 5 6 6 6 5 7 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 7 4 6 6 6 5 6 6 4 5 6 6 7 6 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 4 7 7 5 3 23 14 10 3 18 18 11 5 21 13 11 5 22 14 9 3 6 4 6 5 6 7 6 6 7 6 3 5 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 7 5 7 6 6 5 7 5 6 6 5 5 6 6 5 4 5 9 27 21 18 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 7 4 7 5 6 5 6 6 4 5 6 6 6 7 5 6 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 4 7 6 6 1 3 23 13 11 4 3 20 16 11 3 8 2 1 1 2 1 2 2 2 2 1 3 3 2 3 1 2 1 1 3 2 6 22 13 5 5 25 11 7 6 2 6 3 7 5 6 6 7 5 7 6 5 3 6 6 7 6 6 7 5 6 6 7 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 5 6 3 6 6 4 5 7 29 22 12 7 4 5 5 5 3 5 2 5 23 12 6 2 4 3 25 13 7 2 2 5 23 13 5 2 9 22 10 5 2 5 4 6 5 6 7 6 5 7 6 5 4 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 5 7 6 7 6 7 5 7 6 6 5 6 6 5 6 5 6 4 6 4 8 28 22 14 6 5 6 7 5 6 7 6 7 5 7 6 6 5 8 5 5 6 5 6 6 5 5 5 6 5 6 7 6 6 5 6 6 6 7 6 6 5 6 6 7 3 2 12 21 11 2
2 9 21 17 12 2 2 5 4 6 5 6 6 6 7 6 7 5 3 6 6 5 7 7 6 6 5 6 7 6 7 5 7 6 6 6 5 6 6 5 6 5 5 6 5 5 6 14 25 24 18 9 5 7 7 5 6 7 6 5 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 6 5 6 5 5 6 4 5 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 5 6 7 6 6 7 6 6 4 2 13 21 16 11 3 12 21 16 11 9 20 18 13 3 3 6 3 7 5 6 7 6 5 7 6 5 4 6 5 7 7 6 6 6 5 6 7 6 7 5 7 6 6 5 6 5 6 6 5 5 6 6 4 5 4 12 22 26 20 12 6 6 7 5 6 7 6 6 6 6 7 6 5 6 6 5 6 5 6 5 5 5 5 6 5 6 6 6 5 6 6 6 5 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 4 3 3 2 7 21 19 14 5 1 2 7 19 18 12 5 3 6 7 19 19 17 5 2 6 3 7 5 6 6 7 5 7 6 5 4 6 6 6 6 7 6 5 6 19 7 6 7 5  6 9 6 5 6 5 6 5 5 6 5 6 4 6 4 7 23 27 18 17 5 7 6 6 5 7 6 6 6 6 6 7 6 5 7 4 6 5 6 5 6 6 4 4 7 5 6 7 5 6 5 6 6 5 7 6 6 6 7 6 5 7 19 19 12 6 2 9 21 18 13 2 7 20 18 11 5 2 1 6 4 1 2 6 4 7 5 6 6 6 6 7 6 5 4 6 5 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 5 5 6 6 4 6 5  12 26 24 17 12 5 7 6 6 5 7 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 5 7 4 6 5 6 5 6 6 4 4 7 5 6 6 6 6 5 6 6 5 7 7 6 6 6 6 5 2 9 20 17 11 4 2 7 20 18 12 4 2 9 20 17 12 3 6 17 21 14 5 5 5 4 7 5 6 6 7 5 8 6 3 5 6 5 7 7 5 7 5 6 6 7 6 7 6 6 6 6 6 6 5 6 5 6 5 6 6 4 4 6 13 26 23 19 10 7 6 7 5 6 7 6 6 6 6 7 5 6 7 5 5 6 5 6 5 5 5 5 6 5 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 6 7 6 6 1 6 2 7 19 17 13 5 2 9 22 18 12
20 15 1 2 1 3 2 1 3 18 20 6 12 35 32 35 34 34 34 34 33 34 33 36 44 68 33 32 34 33 34 32 34 35 32 32 35 32 33 36 35 33 33 34 32 34 35 32 32 35 34 38 50 33 39 32 39 37 34 35 34 33 33 82 46 36 33 34 32 34 35 32 22 4 16 33 33 35 32 32 35 34 32 33 34 32 34 33 33 33 35 32 32 35 32 34 49 55 32 38 33 34 32 35 32 33 34 34 32 33 34 34 32 33 33 33 33 33 33 33 34 34 35 32 33 34 34 55 68 47 32 34 33 34 34 32 35 32 34 33 32 34 33 34 31 33 33 32 35 32 32 35 32 32 33 33 32 34 32 33 34 32 33 31 33 33 32 33 32 32 22 4 34 34 32 35 34 32 34 61 44 32 35 33 33 34 33 34 32 35 32 34 34 35 33 33 34 35 40 36 38 59 39 41 34 46 51 42 51 71 77 38 70 35 49 50 55 52 57 62 68 51 63 58 42 54 40 32 51 61 51 61 50 34 63 37 62 56 62 68 74 73 51 69 56 40 51 74 58 73 37 42 50 61 66 61 72 33 34 34 33 34 34 34 32 35 34 32 52 42 34 33 34 34 34 33 34 34 32 35 33 33 34 33 34 34 33 34 34 32 35 34 32 33 35 33 33 34 34 33 33 35 33 33 51 34 33 33 33 34 32 35 32 32 35 32 32 35 32 34 33 33 37 35 32 34 33 32 32 33 33 12 14 21 36 34 33 33 35 34 34 33 34 34 34 34 34 35 32 34 34 35 32 34 34 35 33 34 33 35 34 29 34 34 33 34 34 34 34 33 34 34 34 33 36 32 34 34 35 34 32 34 35 34 32 34 35 34 33 33 35 34 34 34 33 34 34 32 35 34 32 34 33 34 32 35 34 32 33 34 32 33 34 32 33 34 32 33 34 32 34 33 32 33 34 32 33 32 34 31 2 36 37 33 35 33 57 50 34 35 33 33 35 34 34 32 35 34 34 33 34 35 33 34 34 35 33 33 34 35 34 32 34 35 34 34 33 34 34 32 34 35 33 33 33 34 33 33 35 34 34 32 35 34 59 40 34 34 34 34 33 34 34 34 34 35 33 33 34 35 33 33 34 35 34 32 35 35 53 56 55 39 68 34 34 35 32 34 34 35 34 32 34 35 32 34 34 2 20 32 34 35 34 33 33 35 32 33 34 34 32 33 34 34 34 33 34 34 33 34 33 33 34 37 33 32 33 34 31 34 32 33 33 31 33 32 34 33 30 33 32 34 33 33 33 33 32 31 36 54 47 33 33 33 32 34 33 32 33 34 33 33 33 34 32 35 19 2 7 15
2 1 1 4 4 8 37 19 19 20 16 15 9 4 4 16 5 16 18 12 4 8 6 18 14 18 22 16 20 12 16 8 10 6 15 21 10 10 4 6 14 2 14 8 12 4 6 12 2 4 18 20 19 25 16 18 12 16 16 18 2 9 17 14 18 7 8 3 1 11 16 2 4 5 14 15 1 10 12 15 6 4 13 11 10 9 12 5 11 6 2 16 10 22 11 11 19 16 11 7 5 12 5 11 7 14 15 8 4 2 3 2 5 1 5 12 13 16 7 1 9 7 6 3 1 8 4 8 2 12 2 2 2 25 18 15 13 5 9 5 5 9 15 6 2 2 8 6
2 1 1 2 1 2 10 9 4 4 10 5 10 14 12 17 5 4 14 2 15 7 9 9 10 1 5 3 2 10 12 4 11 21 8 23 9 12 6 35 35 68 97 78 63 56 73 55 93 79 93 88 76 100 77 56 51 24 27 51 84 27 15 10 22 6 27 7 11 22 1 6 5 7 2 5 4 1 19 1 3 2 9 19 18 26 14 14 6 3 21 30 6 18 20 9 11 1 10 3 2 3 5 2 20 16 8 5 42 54 11 32 6 24 47 4 2 8 6 39 3 13 11 2 2 5 6 12 3 9 2 2 26 2 6 28 9 1 7 2 2 2 1 15 7 14 9 2 11 9 8 6 1 4 3 5 6 13 16 10 2 1 37 14 6 1 1 1 28 36 7 6 2 12 3 1 10 3 16 2 1 1 2 3 1 8 4 3 5 6 3 3 8 18 1 2 2 28 5 2 7 2 13 16 2 12 2 2 5 1 2 2 2 1 2 1 1 2 1 1 1
45 146 131 142 130 127 169 121 141 136 112 91 117 108 130 98 142 103 86 58 113 124 87 193 114 142 118 60 33 33 40 33 3 11 7 22 1 18 6 16 15 35 7 12 3 29 25 78 57 28 59 34 28 16 8 11 8 19 22 8 8 6 5 2 10 2 15 2 1 9 21 17 12 18 11 9 10 2 9 8 8 2 30 16 3 2 2 8 19 1 14 2 6 3 1 8 9 6 16 9 5 1 1 11 3 12 1 1 18 6 6 4 1 2 6 10 14 5 3 5 5 11 3 3 15 9 1 8 9 12 16 1 2 10 6 15 11 3 7 13 9 2 4 8 3 5 1 9 1 2 9 2 1 1 2 7 11 3 1 9 14 24 9 8 4 2 1 17 3 9 16 10 5 2 2 11 25 16 8 13 1 8 6 8 1 6 6 6 1 13 11 2 10 26 3 1 14 3 10 3 7 2 11 15 16 2 11 2 1 7 1 1 2 11 13 10 6 14 9 2 8 6 4
14 18 4 22 2 12 28 38 44 22 38 16 14 23 45 17 39 29 2 5 15 11 7 2 8 2 14 10 1 14 3 2 2 9 10 4 22 7 27 34 298 212 209 133 150 161 151 75 74 33 57 36 54 58 48 14 44 50 40 16 24 29 12 10 48 16 25 22 22 41 19 12 9 16 8 2 12 11 27 26 17 31 42 44 59 37 17 7 7 12 10 26 24 12 2 4 10 1 16 3 14 17 12 3 11 4 8 8 2 9 5 16 7 3 8 8 8 7 4 32 14 26 20 22 18 23 15 18 18 17 27 23 13 4 8 14 9 5 5 16 7 17 13 3 30 8 2 8 16 6 16 3 28 9 21 3 1 4 4 1 1 4 24 18 6 18 16 18 14 9 7 25 3 2 4 10 2 2 26 35 21 2 1 1 13 2 1 13 21 10 4 15 10 15 25 3 24 8 10 3 2 6 39 11 5 8 2 2 7 1 13 4 12 4 19 57 16 14 20 16 4 4 18 21 12 2 2 6 2 1 4 2 2 1 1 1 1 2 2 1 10 18 5 4


Thank you for your approach! Actually, I prefer using the originally posted data as this is real world data.

@Martin Real world data is usually inadequate for testing a potential solution with as it rarely contains all the outliers and rainy day cases that a solution has to be able to handle (and are often what causes the bulk of the code to be written). It's better for testing to create a MCVE that contains all of the outliers (e.g. all the same, all different, edge cases between 2 percent values, etc. in this case).
